# Печать заголовка на каждой странице

Tags: javascript, html, css

Проблема с печатной формой. 
Письмо которое формируется динамически. Т.е. заранее не известно количество страниц. 
Структура письма заключена в 'table'. Необходимо повторение шапки письма на всех страницах. Свойство table-header-group не работает категорически. 
Чтобы исключить вопрос о правильности его применения, поясню, у меня на компе в браузерах работает, а у клиента нет. Т.е нужна какая-то альтернатива. 
Пыталась сделать через position fixed, не получилось, т.к. если текста много и он оказывается на второй странице, он идет "под" шапкой, может быть есть варианты у вас решения такой проблемы ?

Comment: я сталкивался c таким, единственный выход который я придумал это ручная вставка разрыва страницы с маргинами вверху и внизу. а элементы колонтитулов позиционировал fixed

Comment: @DzianisSadouski, спасибо за версию, попробовала, не получилось(